# Setup fails to run from CD-ROM but works from hard drive

Tags: windows-7, installshield

I have an installation package created in Installshield. When trying to run it in Windows 7, if I copy the files to the hard drive or run them from a network drive, the install runs fine.

If I burn the installation package to a CD and try to run the setup from there, Windows 7 says

> setup.exe is not a valid Win32
>   application

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is your file got corrupted during the burn.  You should verify the burned copy is the same as the copy on the hard drive.

Does the file run properly if you copy it from the CD to the hard drive and run from there?

I use Cygwin's `md5sum` and `diff` tools for verifying suspect burns.  There are lots of other tools that can verify that two copies of a file are the same.

Comment: +1 This seems a bit unlikely, but it's possible.

Comment: hard to tell without more information from the OP.